# update inner collection in MongoDB

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I have a document collection like given below, I need to check the inner collection RuleList if value exists then update the collection or else insert the new item to the collection RuleList using mongodb c#. I was able to update the RuleName and RuleDesc by query with the objectId.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4fb21439f31dfd122ce39c4a"),
    "RuleName": "Rule 1",
    "RuleDesc": "Rule for log"
    "RulesList":[{
        "No" : "1",
        "Name" : "LogRule",
        "Field" : "Log"},{
        "No" : "2",
        "Name" : "IDRule",
        "Field" : "IDEntry"}]
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

In C# simplest way to perform this operation is to use **BsonDocument** class from Official Mongo DB C# driver (http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/)

For each document in collection, you need to first take  "RulesList" *AsBsonArray*. On BsonArray you can perform LINQ query.

Let say for above document you want to check if any item inside "RuleList" array has "Log" value in "Field" property ?

```
  var result = document["RulesList"].AsBsonArray.Any(b => b["Field"].AsString == "Log");
  if (result)
  {
     //do update
  }
  else
  {
     //do insert
  }
```